# Decode SEGD file and plot any trace from it

Tags: python, physics, geo, petrel

There is a SEGD file with some seismic data. How to decode any trace ?

The python script can read and decode headers according SEGD Rev 2.1 documentation. How to decode and plot any trace. Have tried to use 1 byte quatery exponebt data recording method. But having wrong result.
The Data Body:

'10111110',
 '00101001',
 '11001111',
 '00010010',
 '10111101',
 '10100110',
 '00110010',
 '00100100',
 '10111100',
 '10010000',
 '10000100',
 '10010101',
 '00111101',
 '10101001',
 '00010110',
 '00100010',
 '00111110',
 '00001000',
 '10010001',
 '11011010',
 '00111101',
 '10101001',
 '00010110',
 '00100010',
 '00111100',
 '10011100',
 '00010100',
 '10001011',

expecting to get something like

```
    1.000e+00,  1.000e+00,  1.000e+00,  1.000e+00,  3.125e-02,
    1.000e+00,  1.000e+00,  1.000e+00,  1.000e+00,  1.000e+00,
    1.000e+00,  1.000e+00,  1.000e+00,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,
    3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,
    3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,
    3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,
    3.125e-02,  3.125e-02, -1.000e+00, -1.000e+00, -1.000e+00,
   -1.000e+00, -1.000e+00, -1.000e+00, -1.000e+00, -1.000e+00,
    3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  3.125e-02,  7.000e+00,
    2.600e+01,  4.100e+01,  6.100e+01,  7.500e+01,  7.400e+01,
    5.900e+01,  3.600e+01,  1.500e+01,  1.000e+00, -7.000e+00,
   -1.200e+01, -1.300e+01, -1.400e+01, -1.200e+01, -1.000e+01,
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a struct. Create a format, and use it to read the file at the start of the trace, viz.

```
    tracedataformat = '!' + str('f' * ns)
    f.seek(pos)
    tr = np.zeros(ns, np.float)
    tr = np.array(struct.unpack(format, f.read(4 * ns)))
```

- Read 32-bit floats in IEEE format
- ns - the number of samples to read (get it from the channels descriptor)
- pos - the position in bytes relative to the start of the file of the start of the trace.